# Stacked barplot with ggplot2 depending on two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a stacked barplot using ggplot2, which should represent the number of actions, divided in "clicked" or "dismissed" for each user.

The data look like this:

```
ID;User;All;clicked;dismissed
1;andre;3;3;0
2;bianca;23;14;9
3;corinna;51;31;20
4;pfeifer;8;7;1
```

Find below some my current approach, which totally useless until now, and some sample data

[image]

```
# Load data
Temp <- read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LtYsjY89", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ";")
# Load package
library(ggplot2)
# Plot
ggplot(Temp, aes(x=User, fill=All)) +
geom_bar() + 
scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "green", high = "red")
```

As you can see....the total number of the "All"-Variable is applied. What I try to realize: For each user a stacked bar should be created, which presents the the partitioning of the "All"-variable using the "clicked" and "dismissed" values. Thereby, the "clicked" and "dismissed" bar-part should have different colors.
Similar approaches suggest to melt the data (from wide to long), but I do not see the benefits for my use case.

Comment: Whether you can see the benefits in advance or not, melting the data from wide to long is indeed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to melt the data (per @Gregor's comment). The reason is that to map "clicked" and "dismissed" to color, you need a single column that marks which counts come from "clicked" and which from "dismissed". Melting to long format is how you create that column.

```
library(reshape2)

Temp.m = melt(Temp, id.var=c("ID","User","All"))

# Plot
ggplot(Temp.m, aes(x=User, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Although I have looked at the melt part, but I have misinterpreted the fact on how to use it properly....especially which colums have to be set to id.var. Your answer was very helpful!

Comment: If this answers your question, consider accepting it. Keeps others from spending time on it.